# How accepted were public displays of affection in medieval France?

Tags: middle-ages, europe, early-medieval

Were a man and a woman allowed to kiss/hug/hold hands in public? Did it differ depending on whether they were married or not? What about if they were engaged? If it was forbidden, what punishment did they receive?

Edit: I am interested in 10-13th century nobility.

Comment: Medieval Europe is basically ~500 to ~1500, from the Atlantic to the Volga, the Mediterranean to the Arctic Circle. Over two dozen languages and several different religions including paganism in the eastern and Islam in the south-west (Iberia) zone for much of the time period. This question is impossible to answer, in general, over the breadth of that scope.

Comment: Let us be more considerate: in spite of the broadness of the question, we can say general things that e.g kissing (as lovers) was definitely considered a private activity, not something for public display up to later half of 20th century in the most part of the world. Since sex was forbidden outside of marriage, I would expect that being overly intimate with someone in public who is not your marital partner might have been suspicious at least. Or that significant part of marriages was arranged marriage, therefore public affection with your bride would have been technically difficult.

Comment: In bath houses there was a lot of things going on, so much that they may in at least some cases even have been thinly veiled brothels. You may also want to check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnolfini_Portrait

Comment: I'm sorry if the question was too broad/vague, I will edit the post for future references... if two unmarried people of high social class were caught being intimate with each other sometime circa 11th century, what consequences would they face?

Comment: I think this is a good question, and valuable because it's different to most of the war/political stuff we have here. Katerina, I took the liberty of specifying France in the question. France was quite a typical European country, and it should give a starting point for other countries too. If you don't like the edit, feel free to put it back to it was.

Comment: @Greg: That is patently untrue for many Slavs: "*It is a Slavic custom for a man greeting another man to grab him in a bear hug and kiss him three times on the cheek. Some Russian men even go as far as kissing each other on the lips.*".

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Off course, there are always exceptions. However, let us read the question intelligently, in context: it was/is apparently about intimacy related to love life and relationships, not about relatives, underage kids or drunk friends hugging and kissing each other upon meeting. Yes, Eastern Europeans kiss each other when meeting, even men, esp if they are relatives, but it doesn't mean guys were hugging all day and walking around hand in hand in the villages after reading love poems to each other.

Comment: There's plenty of evidence that classical antiquity and the medieval era had little qualms with enjoying themselves. See e.g. https://www.historyextra.com/period/medieval/how-naughty-was-the-past-the-hidden-depths-of-the-medieval-church/ or http://www.medievalists.net/2013/02/sex-in-the-middle-ages/ or, for that matter, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_John_XII who raped countless nuns and pilgrims and turned St Peter's into a brothel. Modern prudishness came later.